# Blender 2.8, Issue with smoothing seam between seperated meshes, and Data Transfer Modifier

Tags: normals, seams

While following the instructions to use Data Transfer to smooth the seams between 2 separated mesh parts, this happens:

[image: image of issue]

The Colour is supposed to be the same as the surrounding meshes. the Normals are not Flipped either. its just displaying much darker than it should be. not sure what the normals are doing here. i followed the instructions to the letter.does anyone know whats going on?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: i undone the separation for now, as i needed to get the mesh usable for uploading to opensim. i'll try recreate it later.